# Trying to pass checkbox list enum value to my view

Tags: string, asp.net-mvc-3, checkbox

Just trying to do some quick and dirty testing. I am passing fake data through my controller to a view just to see how the UI looks.

In my controller which I set up just to "test" this I have, for example:

```
MyViewModel = new MyViewModel
{
  MyModel= new Models.MyModel
  {
      FirstName = "Homer", //This works
      SomeDecimal = 10000, //This works
      SomeRadioButton = Models.MyModel.Enum.Selection, //This works
      SomeCheckBox = Models.MyModel.OtherEnum.OtherSelection, //This doesn't
  }
}
```

I am getting the `Cannot implicitly convert type ... to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'` error.

My radio buttons and check boxes share similar convention for using enums, but the checkbox uses `public List<string> SomeCheckBox { get; set; }` whereas radio buttons use `public Enum? SomeRadioButton { get; set; }`

Please note, I am not using a testing framework. I am just trying to figure out quickly how to pass some fake data to see how the UI is shaping up.  Can anyone share a sample of how to accomplish what I want (to pass a checkbox value so my UI can show data that would have been selected by a user)?

The other problem I forsee is in passing more than one selection from the checkbox, but once I get the code down I think I should be able to figure that out.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error message makes total sense. Try this

```
 var testViewModel = new TestViewModel
 {
     SomeCheckBox = new List<string> {TestViewModel.RadioButtonValues.Value1.ToString() }
 };
```

Comment: Not sure why you feel the need to abuse an enum for this.

Comment: Excellent, thanks! I wish I could say something witty like Beavis about abusing enums, but you'll have to settle for the dull explanation: I needed something consistent for my different inputs and settled on MvcGrabBag, which allows me to call a custom Editor which automagically determines what type of input to create based on my model. Every type of input is handled this way (textbox, multi-line, radio button list, check box list, select list, drop down list). No more three different types of editors with code that is not consistent.